# How to excubate c++ function by lua script?

Tags: c++, lua

i am try to create a simple engine and i dont know how to excubate c++ function by lua with arguments, for example.

c/c++

```
void draw(int TextureID, int x, int y){
     Image.Draw(TextureID,x,y,null); // some function to draw image
}
```

Lua script

```
function main()
   draw(1,1,1)
end
```

someone can help me?

Comment: Do you mean "excubate" in the sense of "sleep outdoors" or "keep watch"?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot export a C++ function directly to Lua: you need to *wrap* it using the Lua-C protocol and the export the wrapper to Lua.

```
static int L_draw(lua_State *L)
{
    int id = luaL_checkint(L,1);
    int  x = luaL_checkint(L,2);
    int  y = luaL_checkint(L,3);
    Image.Draw(id,x,y,null);
    return 0;
}
...
lua_register(L,"draw",L_draw);
```